# Determining integral bounds with law of total probability

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1$ a random variable, $Y_2$ another, with joint density

\begin{align*}
    f(y_1, y_2) = \begin{cases}
        3y_1 & 0 \leq y_2 \leq y_1 \leq 1 \\ 
        0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Let $U = Y_1 - Y_2$. The PDF of $U$ can be obtained in many ways. Using the law of total probability:

\begin{align*}
    P(U \leq u) &= P(Y_1 \leq u + Y_2) \\ 
                &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(Y_1 \leq u + Y_2 \mid Y_2 = y) P(Y_2
                = y) ~ dy \\ 
                &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(Y_1 \leq u + y) f_{Y_2}(y) ~ dy \\ 
                &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y_1}(u + y) f_{Y_2}(y) ~ dy
\end{align*}

We can derive $f_{Y_1}, f_{Y_2}$ from the joint PDF. My question regards the limits of integration. My reasoning is the following. We know $0 \leq y_2 \leq y_1 \leq 1$ is the region where the joint PDF has a non-trivial definition.

Using $u = y_1 - y_2$, we see that $u$ has a minimum point $u=-1$ where $y_1 = 0, y_2 = 1$. We also see that $u$ has a maximum point where $u = 1$ when $y_1 = 1, y_2 = 0$. Then should the integration be

\begin{align*}
    P(U \leq u) 
                &= \int_{-1}^{1} f_{Y_1}(u + y) f_{Y_2}(y) ~ dy
\end{align*}

or am I misinterpreting something?

Answer (score 0):

I will use $X = Y_1$ and $Y = Y_2$, so that the joint density is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 3x, & 0 \le y \le x \le 1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases} \tag{1}$$
Define $U = X - Y$.  Clearly, $0 \le y \le x \le 1$ implies $0 \le X - Y \le 1$, so the support of $U$ is $[0,1]$.

The conditional probability $\Pr[X \le u + Y \mid Y = y]$ is not equal to the unconditional probability $\Pr[X \le u + y]$.  This is because the support of $X \mid Y = y$ is not the same as the support of $X$:  once we are given $Y = y$, we know that $X \in [y, 1]$; whereas the unconditional variable $X$ has support on $[0,1]$.

Concretely, we can compute
$$f_X(x) = \int_{y=0}^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy = \int_{y=0}^x 3x \, dy + \int_{y=x}^1 0 \, dy = 3x^2, \quad 0 \le x \le 1. \tag{2}$$  Similarly,
$$f_Y(y) = \int_{x=0}^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx = \int_{x=0}^y 0 \, dx + \int_{x=y}^1 3x \, dx = \frac{3}{2}(1 - y^2), \quad 0 \le y \le 1. \tag{3}$$

Meanwhile,
$$f_{X \mid Y}(x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} = \frac{3x}{\frac{3}{2}(1-y^2)} = \frac{2x}{1-y^2}, \quad y \le x \le 1. \tag{4}$$  So we can clearly see that $(2)$ and $(4)$ are not equivalent.  As such, the third line in your first equation is incorrect.  The correct computation begins as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\Pr[U \le u] &= \Pr[\color{red}{0 \le} X - Y \le u] \\
&= \Pr[0 \le Y \le X \le u + Y] \\
&= \int_{y=0}^1 \Pr[Y \le X \le u + Y \mid Y = y]f_Y(y) \, dy \\
&= \int_{y=0}^1 F_{\color{red}{X \mid Y}}(u+y) f_Y(y) \, dy, \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
where $$F_{X \mid Y}(x) = \int_{w=y}^x f_{X \mid Y}(w) \, dw = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{1-y^2}, \quad y \le x \le 1 \tag{6}$$ is the cumulative distribution function of the conditional variable $X \mid Y$.  Consequently,
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[U \le u] &= \int_{y=0}^{1-u} F_{X \mid Y}(u + y) f_Y(y) \, dy + \int_{y=1-u}^1 f_Y(y) \, dy \\
&= \int_{y=0}^{1-u} \frac{(u+y)^2 - y^2}{1-y^2} \cdot \frac{3}{2}(1-y^2) \, dy + \int_{y=1-u}^1 \frac{3}{2}(1-y^2) \, dy \\
&= \frac{3}{2} \left( \int_{y=0}^{1-u} (u+y)^2 \, dy + \int_{y=1-u}^1 (1-y^2) \, dy \right) \\
&= \frac{3}{2}u - \frac{1}{2}u^3. \tag{7}
\end{align}$$
It follows that
$$f_U(u) = \frac{3}{2}(1-u^2), \quad 0 \le u \le 1. \tag{8}$$

That said, this approach is unnecessarily complicated.  Instead, it is more direct to compute
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[U > u] &= \Pr[u + Y \le X \le 1] \\
&= \int_{y=0}^{1-u} \int_{x=u+y}^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy \\
&= \int_{y=0}^{1-u} \int_{x=u+y}^1 3x \, dx \, dy \\
&= \int_{y=0}^{1-u} \frac{3}{2} \left(1 - (u+y)^2 \right) \, dy \\
&= \frac{3}{2} \left[y - \frac{(u+y)^3}{3} \right]_{y=0}^{1-u} \\
&= \frac{3}{2} \left((1-u) - \frac{1}{3} - 0 + \frac{u^3}{3}\right) \\
&= 1 - \frac{3}{2} u + \frac{1}{2} u^3. \tag{9}
\end{align}$$
Then
$$f_U(u) = -\frac{d}{du}\Pr[U > u] = \frac{3}{2}(1-u^2), \tag{10}$$
which agrees with the result $(8)$.

---

It is worth mentioning that the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ can be conceptualized as a hierarchical model, namely
$$X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(3,1), \\ Y \mid X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,X).$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. When you say "It is more direct to compute..." and proceed with a double integral, I still don't understand how you determined the integral bounds.

Comment: @lafinur In the triangle defined by $0 \le y \le x \le 1$, for what values of $(x,y)$ is is true that $x-y > u$ for some constant $0 \le u \le 1$?  First, it would help to plot the line $x-y = u$.  Then shade the region that corresponds to the desired inequality.  Then compute the vertices of that region, and consider the appropriate double integral.